# Why is file downloaded with wget jumbled up?

Tags: wget

Why is the file saved with the command:

```
wget http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js
```

all jumbled up? It appears fine in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its gzipped. Try this:

```
$ mv jquery.tools.min.js jquery.tools.min.js.gz
$ gunzip jquery.tools.min.js.gz
$ cat jquery.tools.min.js
```

Comment: How can you tell it's gzipped? Is there a command line tool for that?

Comment: The HTTP headers should tell you. Do `wget --save-headers http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js`. One of the first few lines of the file should contain `Content-Encoding: gzip`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how long this has existed, but on wget version 1.14 you are able to:

```
wget --no-warc-compression http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js
```